# Taking single line input of unknown size separated by spaces and store it to an integer array

Tags: c++

I am using

```
string temp ;
vector <int> arr ;    
while(getline(cin,temp,' '))
{
    arr.push_back(temp);
}
```

but it's not working as I expected and I am getting a compile time error

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::push_back(std::string&)'|
```

Please provide a solution in C++ or C

Comment: You are pushing string when int is expected. `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes advantage of [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which is part of the C++11 standard. `stoi` simply takes a string representation of an integer and turns it into its integer form. i.e. `"123" -> 123`.

```
string temp ;
vector <int> arr ;    
while(getline(cin,temp,' '))
{
   arr.push_back(stoi(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have almost got it right, but your vector type is wrong, you are storing strings, not integers.

```
string temp;
vector<string> arr;
while(getline(cin,temp,' '))
{
    arr.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read the line as a string first, then separate the integers and afterwards push them into the array.

C++11 (I think?) solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr;

    for (std::string temp; std::getline(std::cin, temp); )
    {
        std::istringstream iss(temp);
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(arr));

        for (const auto & elem : arr)
            std::cout << elem << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
        arr.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is you now need a way to stop the infinte loop, but that can be easily solved with a simple condition. It's up to you.